# How to access extension function from inner class[AsyncTask] in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am programming in Kotlin and I have extension function for Date class.

```
fun Date.toString(format: String, locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(format, locale)
    return formatter.format(this)
}
```

It is working fine in `onCreate`, But inside `doInBackground` in `Async task` it gives me error

I have these lines inside `doInBackground`

```
    val currentDateTime = MainActivity().getCurrentDateTime()
    val timeIs = currentDateTime.toString("HH:mm:ss")
```

`getCurrentDateTime()` returns instance of `Date` class
and error is given for the arguments inside `toString()` is

> Too may arguments for public open fun toString():String defined in java.util.Date

I think it is trying to apply Java here like `Date.toString()`.

But how should I solve it?

Comment: How is it invoked?

Comment: @Aivaras I have updated the question, plz check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, that you imported extension function in your class, also check if it class or instance function, latter would not work.
code snippet of your AsyncTask may help.

Extension function, placed inside class, is a member function of enclosing class, so you need reference to instance of that class, e.g of activity, which - is bad idea.
So, putting extension function to companion object or making it static, using @JvmStatic annotation, will make it accessible from other places.

Comment: I have extension function inside my activity

Comment: put function inside companion object of activity, and it should work

Comment: only members in the named object and companion object can be annotated with @JvmStatic

Comment: @Makarand you are not right. Package level functions are legit for static as well.

Comment: "only members in the named object and companion object can be annotated with @JvmStatic"   This was the error I got when I added @JvmStatic annotation on above method which is declared in MainActivity